# Need to get Specific lines of text from a text file C#

Tags: c#, parsing, text-files

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
DeltaV User List - 17 Jun 2013
SUPPLY_CHAIN


UserID              Full Name
BAINC               C M B
BEEMANH             H B
CERIOJI             J M C
LADUCK              K L
MAYC                C M
NEWTONC             C N

DeltaV User List - 17 Jun 2013
FERM_OPER


UserID              Full Name
POULIOTM            M P
TURNERM7            M T
```

I need to get the individual users for each of these sections in C# and I'm not sure how to do it. I was using  the StreamReader class and it worked for getting the Area name (the word in all caps) but I cannot seem to get all of the users. I have a user class that has 2 strings Name & Area and I'm trying to make a list of  user objects.

This is what I've tried so far: (I've declared a list of User objects earlier in the code)

```
        // read user list text file
        var userReader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(UserListPath));

        while(!userReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = userReader.ReadLine();
            var newUser = new User();
            if(line.Contains("DeltaV User List"))
            {
                var Area = userReader.ReadLine();
                newUser.Area = Area;
                userReader.ReadLine();
                userReader.ReadLine();
                userReader.ReadLine();

                var userid = userReader.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(userid);
                var name = userid.Split(' ');
                Console.WriteLine(name[0]);
                newUser.UserId = name[0];
            }
            Users.Add(newUser);
        }
```

Oh, I only need to get the UserId, not the Full Name as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**

Here is a little piece of code that should achieve what you need :

```
        using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(UserListPath))
        using (var userReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        {
            string currentArea = string.Empty;
            string currentToken = string.Empty;
            while (!userReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = userReader.ReadLine();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                {
                    var tokenFound = Tokens.FirstOrDefault(x => line.StartsWith(x));
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenFound))
                    {
                        switch (currentToken)
                        {
                            case AreaToken:
                                currentArea = line.Trim();
                                break;
                            case UserToken:
                                var array = line.Split(' ');
                                if (array.Length > 0)
                                {
                                    Users.Add(new User()
                                    { 
                                        Name = array[0],
                                        Area = currentArea
                                    });
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        currentToken = tokenFound;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This program assumes that your input file ends with a line return. It uses these constants that you will have to declare in your class or anywhere your want by modifying their accessors (`private` into `public` for instance) :

```
private const string AreaToken = "DeltaV";
private const string UserToken = "UserID";

private List<string> Tokens = new List<string>() { AreaToken, UserToken };
```

Of course, i've done it my way, there's probably lots of better way of doing it. Improve it the way you want, it's just a kind of draft that should compile and work.

Among other things, you'll notice :

- the use of [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) keyword, which is very useful to make sure your memory/ressource/file handles are properly free.
- i tried to avoid the use of hard coded values (that's the reason why i use constants and a reference list)
- i tried to make it so you just have to add new constants into the Token reference list (called `Tokens`) and to extend switch cases to handle new file tokens/scenarios

Finally, do not forget to instanciate your `User` list :

```
List<User> Users = new List<User>();
```

Comment: Awesome! It works, but how would I get the Area? I tried adding it to the if(line.StartsWith("DeltaV") condition because it's right underneath the DeltaV line. Can I read the next line in there and then skip the following lines? The area is FERM_OPR for example

Comment: Oops i forgot that you also needed the Area sorry. My code is updated to take this into account ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I got working:

```
void Main()
{
    var filePath = @"..."; //insert your file path here
    var lines = File.ReadLines(filePath); //lazily read and can be started before file is fully read if giant file

    IList<User> users = new List<User>();
    var Area = string.Empty;
    foreach(var line in lines)
    {
       if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) || 
           line.Contains("DeltaV User List") ||
           line.Contains("UserID")
          )
       {
          continue;
       }


    var values = line.Split(' ');
    if(values.Length == 1)
    {
          Area = values[0];
          continue;
    }

    var currentUser = new User
    {
          Name = values[0],
          Area = Area
    };
    users.Add(currentUser);
  }
    users.Dump("User List"); //Dump is a Linqpad method to display result see screen shot
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
}
```

Result from the file you posted:
[image: User Result]

[File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx)

[LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) for testing small snippets of code.

You can copy and paste this into LinqPad to modify for your needs just provide it a file.

Answer (score 1):

```
    // read user list text file
    var userReader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(UserListPath));
    var Area = "";
    while(!userReader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = userReader.ReadLine();
        if(line.Contains("DeltaV User List"))
        {
            Area = userReader.ReadLine();  // Area applies to group of users below.
            userReader.ReadLine(); // blank line
            userReader.ReadLine(); // blank line
            userReader.ReadLine(); // User ID header line
        }
        else
        {
            if (line.trim() != "") // Could be blank line before "DeltaV..." 
            {
                var userid = line;
                var newUser = new User();
                newUser.Area = Area;
                // I left the following lines in place so that you can test the results.
                Console.WriteLine(userid);
                var name = userid.Split(' ');
                Console.WriteLine(name[0]);
                newUser.UserId = name[0];
                Users.Add(newUser);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should really be using string.Empty instead of "" to show intent. This way another dev doesn't come down the line and say hey is this wrong did they forget a value here, etc